# Flag own questions,answers and comments?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that you are allowed to flag **your own answers,comments and questions.** I do not understand why one would ever do that.
So what's the whole point of flagging your own stuff?
*Please note:* If you would like to down-vote this question , at least be kind enough to tell me in the comments.

Comment: And again , funny how the community down votes this question for no reason.

Comment: Funny how often requests comments for downvotes come in, and then get more of them.  People disagree with you.  It happens.

Comment: @fbueckert, yup i am learning :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's various reasons...

- What if someone's never posted a question, answer or comment, but has something really offensive in their profile?
- What if you change your mind about one of your answers but it's accepted so you can't delete it and you therefore want it disassociated from your account?
- What if someone keeps vandalising one of your questions/answers and you want to complain about that.

etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes flag my own questions if I later find that it's a duplicate but that it hasn't got enough flags for removal.